# How to prevent duplicate entries in database

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to implement a friend request feature and using oracle 11 xe database.
My user1 sends a request to user2 so a record in database is created as

**requestId**: 12,
**fromUser**: user1,
**toUser**: user2,
**status** : 0  (indicating pending),
**creationTime**: timestamp

I want to prevent the same entry i.e user1 can send friend request only once not twice. request Id is primary key and user1 and user2 are both foreign keys.
what kind of oracle database constraint or sql command i should add to my table .
Please help

Comment: use a unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a unique combination of **requestId**, **fromUser** and **toUser** and such that none of the columns could never be NULL. Then make the combination as Primary Key.

Alternatively, if you want to allow NULL values for and only want **fromUser** and **toUser** to always be **UNIQUE**, then create a unique index on them and create a unique constraint. The unique constraint will use the unique index.

For example,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indx_usr_uk
  ON table_name (fromUser, toUser);

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (fromUser, toUser);
```

If you don't explicitly create an unique index, then Oracle will use any existing index.

Answer (score 0):

You might have combination of 'fromUser','toUser' columns as primary key. As one user can send the friend request to another user, only once.